# $n$th element of sequence $1223334444\ldots$ where $M$ occurs $M$ times

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do find the $n$'th element of this sequence 
$$122333444455555666666\ldots$$
Here the integer $M$ occurs $M$ times. Say if $M$ is given as $6$ then we don't move ahead of what I have written else if $M$ is $7$ we keep adding $7$ seven times and so on.
The solution in the book is 
Floor of (√2n+1/2) .But couldn't get how ?

Comment: What have you tried? For example, list the first 20-30 elements in a table, and maybe try figuring out the 100th element by hand (and a few others further out) to see if you get any useful ideas or insights.

Comment: What do you do for $M=11?$ Do you have $11$ characters that are $11$, or $12$ characters that are $1$?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if you denote the $k$th term as $T_k$, then:

Terms $T_{\frac 12 (n)(n-1) + 1}$ to $T_{\frac 12 (n)(n+1)}$ inclusive will be all $n$.

Those subscripts are related to triangular numbers.

Comment: Looks like we can write $T_n = [\sqrt{2n}]$ where $[\cdot]$ is the closest integer function.

Comment: @Winther Yes, I wanted the asker to come up with that sort of insight though. At larger $n$ values, $n^2$ is a good approximation to $n(n+1)$.

Comment: Well it's just a guess and the real work is anyway to prove it. Though it's not really needed, a description of the sequence like you have started on here should be good enough imo. A formula like the one above just makes it a bit simpler to compute the $n$'th term.

Comment: The book suggests a solution to this problem as I have updated but how do we get this ?